# Line integral in terms of Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral

**Background**

I have been looking at the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) and I am wondering why (or even if) it is well-defined in the context of Lebesgue integrals.

The [definition of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition) defines it like this (in terms of Riemann integrals, as far as I can tell):

> For some scalar field $f:U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the line integral along a piecewise smooth curve $C \subseteq U$ is defined as $$\int_C f(\mathbf{r}(s)) ds = \int_a^b f(\mathbf{r}(t)) |\mathbf{r}'(t)| dt$$ where $\mathbf{r}:[a,b] \to C$ is an arbitrary bijective parametrization of the curve $C$ such that $\mathbf{r}(a)$ and $\mathbf{r}(b)$ give the endpoints of $C$ and $a<b$.

Note that the first integral in the definition is just notation, its meaning is defined in terms of an arbitrary parametrization. In order for the definition to be well-defined, it is important that any choice of parametrization gives the same result.

---

**Question**

If we are working with the Lebesgue integral, an appropriate definition of the line integral seems to be (feel free to suggest an alternative defintion)

> For Lebesgue measurable $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and Lebesgue measurable function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$, the line integral along a piecewise smooth curve $C \subseteq U$ is defined as $$\int_C f(\mathbf{r}(s)) ds = \int_{[a,b]} f(\mathbf{r}(t)) |\mathbf{r}'(t)| dt$$ where $\mathbf{r}:[a,b] \to C$ is an arbitrary bijective parametrization of the curve $C$.

I relaxed the restriction on $f$ to be any Lebesgue measurable function, and removed the restriction that $\mathbf{r}(a)$ and $\mathbf{r}(b)$ must be endpoints of $C$, because the Lebesgue integral ignores the "order" in which we integrate over the space (we still integrate over the whole $C$ because $\mathbf{r}$ is bijective). Again, the first integral is just notation, and the definition of this notation is in terms of an arbitrary parametrization.

**Is the definition in terms of the Lebesgue integral well-defined?** Concretely, these questions come to mind:

- What should be the interpretation of *smooth* in these definitions? Suggestion based on the comment by @PaulSinclair: A set is a smooth curve iff it has a bijective parametrization that has continous first-order partial derivatives almost everywhere.
- Is the definition independent of the parametrization?
- Is the Lebesgue integral always defined, for any measurable function and any smooth curve?

If so, why (proof)? If not, what should I change such that the definition becomes well-defined? If there are any resources on this (books, ...), I am interested in that as well.

Comment: Recall that if $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then it is also Lesbegue integrable and the two integrals are the same. (And btw, either of the integrals can be written as $\int_a^b$ or as $\int_{[a,b]}$. These notations do not distinguish between them.) Thus your questions are already answered. Since the functions being integrated are the same, the Lesbegue integral is well-defined for the same functions as the original (with the conditions on $r$ that you didn't duplicate added back in).

Comment: You can allow more general functions/paths for the Lesbegue integral version if you wish, but only so far as the Lesbegue integral is still defined. The normal definition of smooth here is "having continous first-order partial derivatives". And with Lesbegue integrals you can always weaken conditions to hold only "almost everywhere". But this is less of a generalisation of "piecewise smooth" than it may seem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for your helpful comments! I have updated the question based on your insights. It seems to me that now, we cannot simply refer to the Riemann-version being well-defined. I have also explained my interpretation of well-defined a bit more.

Comment: You should take into account that a function may be Lebesgue measurable on $R^n$, but its restriction to the hyperplane with $x_1=0$ may not! In general, even this problem is not trivial and one has to consider only special classes of $R^n$-measurable functions for restrictions. If you only want to evaluate integrals of "general" functions on a curve, you can regard the curve as a measurable space in itself, and apply the Lebesgue theory to it (with some adaptations).

Comment: @Peter The problem arises indeed, because A is negligible wrt the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, but clearly it is not so wrt the $n-1$-dimensional measure. For example, let $f$ be not measurable on $R$. Consider $F: R^2 \rightarrow R$ such that $F(x, 0) = f(x)$, $F(x, y)=0$ if $y\ne 0$: $F$ is almost everywhere null in $R^2$ and is measurable, but its restriction to the curve $\lbrace (t, 0) : t \in R \rbrace$ (regarded as the measurable space $R$) is not measurable.

Comment: @Peter: the Lebesgue measure has the property that every subset of a negligible set is (measurable and) negligible. This is not true for measures on a general measurable space, like the one in the post you linked.

Comment: @Peter: I think that "Lebesgue integrable" implies "Lebesgue measurable", but maybe it's only a matter of terminology: can you explain better your previous comment? Anyway, do we agree on the fact that $f$ being measurable (that is, counterimages of open sets of $R$ via $f$ are measurable sets) on $U\subset R^n$ wrt the $n$-dimensional measure does not imply that $f$ is measurable on any subset of $U$, regarded as a measurable space?

Comment: I am not convince by this. Instead of a long discussion, I have opened a separate question on this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492206/restriction-of-measurable-function. Feel free to comment, if I did not write down what you meant. I have also removed my comments on this. It seems better to have a separate discussion.

Comment: @Peter: I hope you get convinced ;)

Comment: Sorry if I look too passionate about this problem, but measure theory is tough and it is easy to neglect key points in measure-theoretical proofs (and consequently, to write bad maths). What you are doing is not a restriction of the Lebesgue measure to a measurable subset of $R^n$: you are introducing the Hausdorff measure on $C$. This construction relies strictly on the metric properties of $R^n$ (so the question you linked in your previous post is set too generally to be useful here), and the link between the two measures is quite problematic

Comment: @SiD: No problem, I am asking here because I want to know about the details. Do you mean that the integral $\int_C f(\mathbf{r}(s)) ds$ is in terms of the Hausdorff measure on $C$? This is not what I meant, and I have now clarified that in an edit. Still, the relation to the Hausdorff measure is a good point that I could ask about in a separate question.